# What are the common tennis terms in Korean?

Tags: nouns

Particularly for

- [advantage set / tiebreaker set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Scoring_a_tiebreak_game)
- game
- set
- match
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)
- 15/30/40
- deuce
- advantage in / advantage out

Answer (score 5):

We commonly use English loanwords when it comes to sports.

- advantage set / tiebreaker set : 어드밴티지 세트
- game 게임, 경기
- set 세트
- match 매치, 경기, 시합
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation) : 러브게임, 무득점 경기, 러브 
  ex) 이번 게임은 러브로 끝났다.
- 15/30/40 : 0(love), 15(fifteen), 30(thirty), 40(forty)
- deuce : 듀스
- advantage in / advantage out : 어드밴티지 인, 어드밴티지 아웃.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most Korean use the tennis terms in English when playing tennis. I've been playing tennis with my Korean and American friends, but I have never used any terms in Korean.